# Example in achartengine demo source code show wrong result

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working on charting tools for android. While searching I got `achartengine` tool and I downloaded the demo source code. In this source, is an example of `MultipleTemperatureChart.java`. In this example plots graph with two y-axis and one x-axis.
The strange thing I notice is that when I simply pass a value on my own in the code instead of the value that is given in the example code. What I notice is that the graph plot against the `left y-axis` and `x-axis` is fine. But the graph plot using the `right y-axis` and `x-axis` is wrong. Why this happens? Is anything wrong in the code? The changes I made in code are shown in `**` sign in the code I paste below.

```
public Intent execute(Context context) {
String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete" };
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  **x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4});
}
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
**values.add(new double[] { 10, 15, 20, 25});
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW };
PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND,
    PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);
int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
}
setChartSettings(renderer, "Average temperature", "Month", "Temperature", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 32,
    Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
renderer.setXLabels(12);
renderer.setYLabels(10);
renderer.setShowGrid(true);
renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });

renderer.setYTitle("Hours", 1);
renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
values.clear();
**values.add(new double[] { 10, 15, 20, 25});
addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Sunshine hours" }, x, values, 1);
Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer,
    "Average temperature");
return intent;
}
```

**Screenshot for the graph I found after this changes**

[image]

Comment: How did you make it work? when I try this example I obtain always an error...the application doesn't start...

Answer (score 0):

You have only one x-axis, i.e.:

```
x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Don't you need another one?